# How does multiprocessing Pool(processes=n) handle excessive Pool requests?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Assume I have code like the following--where I need to run a function (with different params) x times. However, my Pool count is less--e.g. x/2.

```
args_list = []

# Range(8) is just an example. My args are more complex.
for r in Range(8):
    args_list.append(r)

with Pool(4) as proc_pool:
    results = proc_pool.map(my_func, args_list)
    proc_pool.close()
    proc_pool.join()
```

**Will `Pool` only try to process 4 at a time--then move on to the next 4, or will all 8 be processed at once--but only in 4 Pools?**

If Pool will try to process all 8 in 4 Pools at once, what is the best way to handle this? (I can put the `with Pool` code in a loop to only use 4 Pools at once.)

**I read the documentation, but it was not clear to me.**

Comment: It just queues them. In your case the final 5th item will not be processed until one of the first 4 items have completed.

Comment: Read the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#module-multiprocessing.pool

Comment: The documentation actually isn't very clear unless you're already familiar with thread/process/worker pools.  Here is Wikipeda's page on Thread pools (which applies to python process pools): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number passed in `Pool`'s first argument is the number of worker processes in the pool (in this case 4).  The map function will run on each argument.  Each time a worker finished it's available to be used to run another argument.

To illustrate this, consider the following:

```
import time
def my_func(r):
   if r == 1:
       time.sleep(120)
   return r * r
```

The first thing that will happen is that 4 runs will be sent the workers.  All of them will finish almost immediately, except for the one which `r == 1`.  As the workers finish, the worker is re-used for another input.  So, in the example, 7 of the workers will finish almost immediately but the last one will take about 2 minutes.  Since the map function will wait until all workers finish to return the results, the map function will take 2 minutes to finish.

To give another example:

```
import time
def my_func(r):
   if r in (1, 3, 5, 7):
       time.sleep(120)
   return r * r
```

Half of the runs will complete almost instantly, where 4 of the runs will take 2 minutes.  If five of the runs would take 2 minutes (say for `r in (1, 2, 3, 5, 7)`), the total time would be 4 minutes, since for 2 minutes 4 processes would be waiting and for 2 minutes 1 process would be waiting.